# Joomla - vertically allign multiple lines of text

Tags: html, css, menu, vertical-alignment, joomla3.0

Long time listener, first time caller.

I am creating a custom Joomla! template and have an issue with vertically aligning multiple lines of text within my horizontal menu.

Ordinarily I would get around this by setting the line height
and wrapping the problematic text in a span tag with

```
display: inline-block;
vertical-align: middle;
line-height: normal;
```

However - using the Joomla! menu doesn't allow me access to the inner
markup to add the span tag.

I can get a good result by applying:

```
ul.nav.menu li {
    width:14.2857%;
    float:left;
    display:block;
    line-height:50px;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}

ul.nav.menu a {
   display:inline-block;
   vertical-align: middle;
   line-height: normal;
}
```

But then the clickable area is limited to the text itself and not the entire li.
Which is a problem, more so because I intend to use rollover buttons.

Does anyone have any suggestions to overcome this?

Comment: Alas, the line-height trick only works when you have a single line. As for the whole area being clickable, I haven't tried, but what happens if you add a `min-width: 100%` to the `ul.nav.menu.a` phrase?

Comment: Hi! Since some time, Joomla has its own StackExchange site: [joomla.stackexchange.com](http://joomla.stackexchange.com). You might get answers there. Please consider moving your question there (delete it from [SO] and paste question text at [joomla.stackexchange.com](http://joomla.stackexchange.com)).